# Qt keyboard events with DirectX fullscreen

Tags: windows, qt, directx

I need to display a full screen DirectX window from a Qt app.

Although directX isn't supported directly anymore by Qt this should be easy enough - just override QWidget, provide your own paintEvent() and set a WA_PaintOnScreen attribute.

But when the app is full screen DirectX is grabbing all the mouse and keyboard inputs - so the only way out of the app is ctrl-alt-del.

ps. Even if I wrote DirectX keyboard handlers I would still have to find a way of creating the correct Qkeypress event to pass to Qt.

Has anyone done this? Or is there a simple way to tell DirectX not to grab the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge Direct3D does not get the keyboard.  Your problem more likely arises from the fact that Direct3D in full-screen is quite a different beast.  Things like GDI (which Qt may well use to do rendering) do not work by default, the run-time hooks lots of bits of information.  That info then, presumably, never manages to get to Qt.  The options you have are to re-implement Qt to render using Direct3D (Lighthouse project?) or to use a pseudo full screen.  This is usually done by creating a window that has a client area the same size as the screen and then positioning it correctly.

The latter would probably be the simplest solution ...

Comment: Yes I only need D3D for the full screen part - so I simply draw direct to the D3D surface from within Qt. The hot keys that are part of the D3D driver still work - so it looks like I have to write some sort of D3D keyb hook.  It also means that drawing a Qt menu over the D3D surface is probably very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There was an attempt to get a D3DWidget kind of thing in Qt 4.3-4.5 or something like that, but it never was stabilized or approved and later even removed.

Perhaps indeed lighthouse is an option (with a medium sized amount of work, basically links OS/DX stuff to Qt stuff) or you can take a look at the old direct3D code in older Qt branches. I never used it, and it probably isn't intended to use with recent versions of Qt, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: The DirectX renderer was removed (supposedly) because they wanted cross platform and Qt's future is really on cellphones.

Comment: @Martin: indeed, I read that between the lines as well... OpenGL is nicely integrated, that's a plus!